# Use CodeMirror editor for both CSS and HTML on the same page

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to load the CodeMirror editor to be used in a plugin backend. Some textareas are for HTML and some are for CSS. I am quite new to WP development, so pardon my ignorance, but doing this:

```php
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'joermo_enqueue_scripts');
    function joermo_enqueue_scripts($hook) {
        $joermo_html_code['ce_html'] = wp_enqueue_code_editor(array('type' => 'text/html'));
        $joermo_css_code['ce_css'] = wp_enqueue_code_editor(array('type' => 'text/css'));
        wp_localize_script('jquery', 'joermo_html_code', $joermo_html_code);
        wp_localize_script('jquery', 'joermo_css_code', $joermo_css_code);

        wp_enqueue_script('wp-theme-plugin-editor');
        wp_enqueue_style('wp-codemirror');
    }
```

I only get the one that is last declared, here CSS. How can I get both?

This is my js:

```js
jQuery( function() {
    wp.ce_html.initialize(jQuery('.joermo-html-code-editor'), joermo_html_code);
} );
```

And HTML:

```html
<textarea class="joermo-html-code-editor" name="shipping_label_text">' . $shipping_label_text . '</textarea>
```

And also, is it not possible to .initzialie() several textareas with a shared class in one go? Do I have to call each one by id?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this exact issue and with a tiny bit of tweaking it should work, what you have is 90% of the way there.

I've tweaked your code slightly so it should now work.

**The PHP:**

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'joermo_enqueue_scripts');
function joermo_enqueue_scripts($hook) {
    $joermo_code['ce_html'] = wp_enqueue_code_editor(array('type' => 'text/html'));
    $joermo_code['ce_css'] = wp_enqueue_code_editor(array('type' => 'text/css'));
    wp_localize_script('jquery', 'joermo_code', $joermo_code);

    wp_enqueue_script('wp-theme-plugin-editor');
    wp_enqueue_style('wp-codemirror');
}
```

**The jQuery:**

```
jQuery(function() {
    wp.ce_html.initialize(jQuery('.joermo-html-code-editor'), joermo_code);
    wp.ce_css.initialize(jQuery('.joermo-css-code-editor'), joermo_code);
});
```

Before I got the above working, I tried exactly the same as you did with running `wp_localize_script` twice. But `$joermo_html_code['ce_html']` & `$joermo_css_code['ce_css']` can be switched to an array and then you only need to run localize once. So in my example it became `$joermo_code['ce_html']` & `$joermo_code['ce_css']`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This approach might be easier to read. wp.codeEditor.initialize must be used for both, just passed the desired setting.

**PHP**

```
wp_register_script('cm_js', plugins_url('js/admin_codemirror.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '0.1.0', true);
$cm_settings = array(
    'ce_css' => wp_enqueue_code_editor(array('type' => 'text/css')),
    'ce_html' => wp_enqueue_code_editor(array('type' => 'text/html'))
);
        
wp_localize_script( 'cm_js', 'cm_settings', $cm_settings );
wp_enqueue_script( 'cm_js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-theme-plugin-editor' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-codemirror' );
```

**JS**

```
wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#id_for_css'), cm_settings.ce_css);
wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#id_for_html'), cm_settings.ce_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. But i found a solution.

PHP:

```
    $cm_settings = wp_enqueue_code_editor( array( 'type' => 'text/css' ) );
    $cm_settings2 = wp_enqueue_code_editor( array( 'type' => 'application/javascript' ) );

    wp_localize_script('jquery', 'cm_settings', $cm_settings);
    wp_localize_script('jquery', 'cm_settings2', $cm_settings2);

    wp_enqueue_script('wp-theme-plugin-editor');
    wp_enqueue_style('wp-codemirror');
```

JS:

```
  wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#batheme_custom_css_textarea'), cm_settings);
  wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#batheme_custom_js_textarea'), cm_settings2);
```

Now both work like a charm. :)

Comment: That looks basically the same as Aaron's answer except you're passing the two wp_enqueue_code_editor results as separate variables? And it's now wp.codeEditor not separate ce_html and ce_css?

Comment: Basically, maybe, but Aaron's approach didn't work for me.

Comment: In my case, wp.ce_js and wp.ce_css threw 'undefined' in console. I had to use wp.codeEditor and two separate config objects.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without an additional JS file:

```php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_page_editor' );

function my_admin_page_editor() {

    global $pagenow;

    if ( ( 'admin.php' === $pagenow ) && ( 'my-options-page' === $_GET['page'] ) ) {

        $custom_css = wp_enqueue_code_editor( array( 'type' => 'text/css' ) );
        $header_js  = wp_enqueue_code_editor( array( 'type' => 'application/javascript' ) );
        $footer_js  = wp_enqueue_code_editor( array( 'type' => 'application/javascript' ) );

        wp_add_inline_script(
            'code-editor',
            sprintf(
                'jQuery( function() {
                    wp.codeEditor.initialize( jQuery( ".my-custom-css textarea" ), %1$s );
                    wp.codeEditor.initialize( jQuery( ".my-header-scripts textarea" ), %2$s );
                    wp.codeEditor.initialize( jQuery( ".my-footer-scripts textarea" ), %3$s );
                });',
                wp_json_encode( $custom_css ),
                wp_json_encode( $header_js ),
                wp_json_encode( $footer_js )
            )
        );
    }
}
```